# Кнопка перед :active становится прозрачной

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Проблема такая, когда клацаешь на кнопку, она становится прозрачной, как исправить?

```css
a.login {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.btn {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 1.25vw;
  background: rgb(251, 87, 88);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fb5758', endColorstr='#eb4974', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  transition: 0.15s;
  margin-left: -2%;
  left: 15%;
}

p.header {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.250em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  cursor: default;
}

div.btn:active {
  background: #404040 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: 0s;
}

div.btn:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  <p class="header">КЛОНДАЙК ТВАРЫНЫ</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#" class="login">ВХОД</a></div>
  <div class="btn"><a href="#" class="login">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: background-color: вместо background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легче всего установить `transition` только на `transform`, если он вам нужен только для масштабирования:

```
div.btn:hover {
    ...
    transition: transform 0.15s;
    ...
}
```

Градиенты, к сожалению, не поддерживают `transition`.

```css
a.login {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.btn {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 1.25vw;
  background: rgb(251, 87, 88);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(251, 87, 88) 0%, rgb(235, 73, 116) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fb5758', endColorstr='#eb4974', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  transition: 0.15s;
  margin-left: -2%;
  left: 15%;
}

p.header {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.250em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  cursor: default;
}

div.btn:active {
  background: #404040 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: 0s;
}

div.btn:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: transform 0.15s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  <p class="header">КЛОНДАЙК ТВАРЫНЫ</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <div class="btn"><a href="#" class="login">ВХОД</a></div>
  <div class="btn"><a href="#" class="login">РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это я уже понял, по сему пришлось задавать цветом. Спасибо :)